# Events in multiple nested layouts fields (OnClickListener)

Tags: java, android, android-layout

To a father layout I am adding successive child layouts in the following way

Parent layout (parent.xml)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ly_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- In principle, the cardview should not interfere with the task.
    I put the code as a precaution. -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/media_card_view"
    ...>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ly_wrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- First row: header -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/row_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    ... />

                <TextView
                    ... />

            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Second row: details -->
            <!-- Programmatically included -->

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Child layout (child.xml)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/child"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        ... />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_image"
        ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

Layouts are nested in a function called createView(), in this function I explain my doubt

```
private void createView() {

    LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.ly_parent));
    LinearLayout wrapper = parent.findViewById(R.id.ly_wrapper);
    LinearLayout child = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.child, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.ly_child));

    wrapper.addView(child);

    ImageView imageView = parent.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);

    //So far everything works correctly

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //In this event I need to add a new child (ly_child).
            //The iv_image field of the newly inserted child must create another child,
            //and so on, Something like this:

            wrapper.addView(child);

            //Get the new ImageView and create the onClickListener event,
            //this process will be repeated an indeterminate number of times.

            //I had managed to add the children's layout but after some tests I
            //modified something and the code fails :(, throws the following exception:
            //"The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

            //I have tried to put a different id to the wrapper layout within the
            //onClickListener event but it still does not work. Something like this:

            //child.setId(); <- Generation of a unique id.
            //wrapper.addView(child);

        }
    });

}
```

A summary could be: I need to add rows (each row is a child layout -child.xml-) and the ImageView of
each row must have its onClick event to create another line. This is repeated indefinitely.

Any ideas? I'm a bit blocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to change this code as below.

```
LinearLayout parent;
LinearLayout wrapper;

private void createView() {

    parent = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.ly_parent));
    wrapper = parent.findViewById(R.id.ly_wrapper);

    addNewChild();
}

private void addNewChild(){
    //update this below line
    LinearLayout child = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.child,null,false);

    ImageView imageView = child.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
    wrapper.addView(child);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addNewChild();

        }
    });
}
```

This will create single child on each `onClick` event and you can set unique id and code execution for each child differently.

Comment: Thank you! I have tested your code and I find the following error. In the line "wrapper.addView (child);" throws me the exception "The specified child already has a parent.You must call removeView () on the child's parent first." I have tried to add the parameter attachToRoot = false in the inflate method and to assign a unique id to the child layout. None of the two works. I have searched all the information I could on the internet and I do not find the solution.